# Wide HTML table runs off right of page - How to enable horizontal scroll bar of browser?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a very wide data view as a plain html table and when it's 100% or more it runs off the right hand side of the browser not allowing entire view of data.

How can I get the browser's horizontal scrollbars to enable so the user can scroll to view entire contents (I have the width set to 100% but that didn't do anything)?

Thx!

Comment: can u post the html for ure table?

Comment: It should be viewable by default, so you probably have CSS included already that is counteracting it (or you have syntax errors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define an area that the table will be displayed in first and then use overflow.

```
<div id="tableview">
     Your table code here
</div>
```

then in your css

```
#tableview {
     width: 500px;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

Adjust the width to suit.

That should constrain your table so that it's displayed in a scrollable area rather than go off the page.

Answer (score 4):

Set the css to be

```
#myTable{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Where myTable is the ID for your table.